# Applescript: play two sounds simultaneously

Tags: audio, applescript

I am using Applescript to test melodies for carillon with the real sounds of bells.
Now, I wish I could play a chord of 2 or 3 notes simultaneously.
So far, this is my best:

```
 do shell script "afplay -t 0.000001 " & (quoted form of (bell1.mp3))
 do shell script "afplay -t 0.2 " & (quoted form of (bell2.mp3))
```

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`do shell script` work synchronously. You need to tell the first call not to wait:

```
do shell script "afplay " & (quoted form of bell1.mp3) & "> /dev/null 2>&1 &"
do shell script "afplay " & (quoted form of bell2.mp3)
```

Comment: I cannot tell how long I need to bless you for your help... Thank you!